# Why do my Google Drive folders have colors?

Tags: google-drive

For a while I have been wondering what is the significance of grey color and green color in my Google Drive. Any idea?

[image: Google Drive Folders]

Comment: Sure you didn't do that yourself? You can "change color" of a folder under the "More" menu.

Comment: Oops.. I probably did... Many years back. I kept wondering all these while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, the only automatic thing Google does to folders is add a person icon to folders that have been shared.

You can change the color of a folder yourself, either by right-clicking on it or checking the box and using the "More" menu.

[image: folder context menu with "change color" option]

The *most likely* explanation is that you changed the color of those folder in the dim-and-distant past and it simply slipped your mind.